# GET a 404 on document request if the route parameter is invalid

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

**My project use Nuxtjs (javascript framework related to vueJs).**
I have a route with a parameters, this parameters is valide only if my api return a JSON and a response 200. This validation is inside the event created on my page.

---

I want in the case is not valide, to get a 404 on the first call on the document, but i think is not possible?

A working example of this is ir https://nuxtjs.org/docs/xxxxx.
You can see the first call inside the network tab return a 404, but i don't know if this parameters is check on the api or not.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question, but this `validate` method is called before navigating to a new route, so it happens before new page is returned to the user.

Comment: @qiqqq Thanks for reply, i have updated my question to be more simplify and generic, i hope you understand.

Comment: you have need this: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-async-data https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-error

Comment: check page exists in `useAsyncData` if not_found call `error` by `useError`. nuxt response page error (not_found)

Comment: @TachibanaShin Is this work in nuxt2? Because i see this before and try but nothing happend, and if i put a console.log inside nothing is print.
I try this: ```useAsyncData({ error }) { return error({ statusCode: 404 }) }```

Comment: if you use nuxt 2 you must use `asyncData()` in options api